# SnapSvg moving image onclick

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

So i am tryingout `Snap svg`

Right now i have the following code:

```
var chatSvg = Snap("#chatSvg");
var c = chatSvg.image('assets/figures/naked.jpg', 10, 10);
chatSvg.click(function (event) {
    c.x = event.x;
    c.y = event.y;
});
```

However once the properties `x` and `y` is changed the image does not move.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change attributes in Snap using the attr() method, which will change the SVG attributes at the lower level for you.

So for example, it would look like

```
c.attr({ x: event.x, y: event.y })
```

Its also worth noting that the x, y coords get passed correctly into the click function, so its generally preferred to use this, so you could change the func to...

```
chatSvg.click( function( event, x, y ) {
    c.attr({ x: x, y: y })
});
```